# How can I clip text in in cell in spreadsheet with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I clip text in in cell in spreadsheet with google apps script?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLXTn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: This has been possible for a while now (see the linked issues that are fixed):

```
range.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP);
```

---

This is not currently possible, you can only set it to wrap or no wrap.

You can follow this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5482). [This one](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5067&q=clip&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) is also related.
If you star the issue it's more likely to be worked on sooner and you will get updates.

Comment: Thanks. I starred this issues.